# No suitable driver found to connect to MySql openshift

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, openshift

I'm trying to connect to MySql from tomcat(jboss) but i'm getting the error

```
 java.sql.SQLException : No suitable driver found
```

I have added the mysql connector jar file in my project lib ,it works fine in my local machine but not working in openshift, for openshift i have changed the username, password and url given by openshift to connect to MySql in my java program but it doesn't work do i have to place the jar file anywhere else...can any one help me with this?

Comment: Here's a forum thread related to your issue that has some suggestions:  https://www.openshift.com/forums/openshift/no-suitable-driver-found-error  Can you review it to see if it helps?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Nam Duong i have seen the forum earlier but it did not help me i am able to connect to mysql and i have loaded my mysql dump into it but i'm not able to connect through java program even though i have added the jar file.

Answer (score 0):

Did you 'git add .' and then 'git commit' to make sure JAR file is on the server?
Is there a reason you can't add the mysql connector jar to the dependencies in the pom.xml?